# Anatomy of $\mathcal P(\mathbb{N})$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

How many proper subsets of $\mathcal P(\mathbb{N})$ there is that have cardinality of $2^{|\mathbb{N}|}$ ?

Comment: The cardinality of $\mathcal P(\mathbb{N})$ is $2^{|\mathbb{N}|}$, so the cardinality of $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(\mathbb{N}))$ is $2^{2^{|\mathbb{N}|}}$.

Comment: This should also be the answer to the question, intuitively.

Comment: This question is about subsets of $\mathcal P(\mathbb{N})$ and some of the subsets are finite and some are infinite. If we "cut off" everything that is countable, then what is left?

Comment: @Juho: Removing everything that is countable is NOT the same as only keeping things of cardinality $2^{|\mathbb N|}$. (It _may_ be the same, but standard set theory does not guarantee that).

Comment: @HenningMakholm:  OK

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ is in bijective correspondence with $\mathbb R$, it may be somewhat more intuitive to rephrase the question to

> How many proper subsets of $\mathbb R$ have the same cardinality as $\mathbb R$ itself?

On one hand there can be at most $2^{|\mathbb R|}=2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ of them, because that's how many subsets of *any* cardinality $\mathbb R$ has.

On the other hand, for every $A\in\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$ you can consider the set
$$ \{x\le 0\mid x\in A\} \cup (0,1) \cup \{x>1\mid x-1\in A\} $$
which has cardinality $|\mathbb R|$ (and is proper because it doesn't contain $1$).

Comment: I was thinking about this question in a discrete sense, but of course when we consider subsets of $\mathbb R$ everything is clear. The power set of Natural numbers bends my brain and I have no intuitive grasp.

Comment: @Juho: Let me tell you the same thing I tell my student at the first lecture every year. If you don't have the proper intuition, it's better to be aware of that, and just work with the basic definitions instead. Then with time you prove all sort of theorems, and eventually develop the right intuition.